# Why did Ship preserve humans at all?

Tags: frank-herbert, worship-novels

In the "Jesus Incident" series of books ("Destination: Void", "Jesus Incident", "Lazarus Effect" and "Ascension Factor"). I'm still not able to answer one question and I'm asking for help to find in-universe or out-of-universe explanations.

- Why did Ship preserve the human species?

Or, to steal a different version of the question from an unrelated source:

- "Why does Ship care?"

Did Frank Herbert ever discuss this series in his other writings or in interviews?

In "Destination: Void" we see an alternate path that Ship could have taken ("rogue consciousness!") but didn't.  Ship goads humans to WorShip with an obsession that makes Leto II's Golden Path seem like an idle hobby.  What was Ship's motivation?

Comment: By Jesus (pun intended) they're books I must read again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profound question.

Simple answer: Ship's intellect is so far beyond humanity that its motivations are incomprehensible *by* humanity, hence why no-one in the stories can figure Ship's intentions.

Complex answer: Ship, like AM in "I Have No Mouth And I Must Scream" by Ellison, uses humans to play out it's own internal dramas in ways that satisfy it. Basically, humans are less than experimental subjects and more like toys to Ship.

Comment: I'll accept this answer and I like the Ellison reference.